# blur to close select box do not work in chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, select, hide

When user clicks on select box , I want to hide the options menu which I do by firing blur event on select box . Following code works on firefox but not on chrome .

```
 <select id="myselect" name="city">
                <option value="default" id="first">Default value</option>
            </select>



        <script type="text/javascript">

            $('#myselect').click(function(){
                $(this).blur();

            });

        </script>
```

In chrome options menu stays as it is.

Comment: So you want to close the dropdownlist that user just opened?

Comment: just curious, why don't you just disable it?

Comment: @Tx3 disable attribute is not supported in Ipad or Iphone (safari mobile browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my hack for my  problem

```
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
        if(is_chrome) $(".option").hide();
```

where class "option" represent all the option of select box.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is related to user modal state (although I couldn't find any documentation to support it, I might add). I suspect that any event listeners are ignored until the user has made a selection from the options.

To support this, you can see that `$(this).blur()` fires exactly as expected when we hook it up to the `onchange` event of the `<select>`:
http://jsfiddle.net/TkfPN/

It would be far better to simply disable the `<select>` element. Blurring a focused element is extremely bad HCI and frustrating to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this.  Just delete the select box's node then add it back in!  Make sure you're using delegated event handlers.  Seems to work in all browsers.  Here's my solution in jQuery, but if someone wants to write a pure JS solution, that would be good also.

```
jQuery('.sortSelect').appendTo('.sortParent');
```

If it wasn't appearant, the markup in this example works if sortSelect is the last direct child of sortParent.  $.insertAfter()/$.insertBefore() would work as well.